# Fried microcontroller while taking a voltage measurement?

Tags: microcontroller, multimeter

Alright, feeling pretty dumb here lol. I was taking a DC voltage measurement with a Fluke 87 V from a pin of a microcontroller to GND, when out came the magic smoke. The pin I was measuring is a 5V output pin. This has happened twice now, I thought the first time my probe may have touched a surrounding pin, but I was extremely careful this time. I've been having trouble with my meter lately - I get erratic readings when trying to zero the leads. Internet search did not yield any results worth speaking of.

I should also say that though this post seems poorly constructed, I'm just looking for obvious issues. I don't want to get into the weeds, just trying to figure out if there's anything that jumps out as an explanation as to why it may have happened.

Comment: Did you see the proper voltage on multimeter display before IC burned? Any chance the probe was plugged in to a current measurement port?

Comment: You should probably provide some more detail such as a part number, data sheet link, which pin being probed and a few things regarding your multi meter including what jacks you had the leads plugged to and the range setting of the selector knob.

Comment: @ chamod - yes sir, I saw about 2.4V before the fireworks started. And no, the probes were plugged into the common and voltage ports. I should have mentioned the issue I was having with my meter is: when trying to zero the test probes for finer resistance measurements, the reading is erratic and will jump from 2-3 ohms, down to 0. @ Michael Karas - the micro is actually an ASIC. I will try to dig something up.

Comment: You should measure the voltage across the same resistor with another meter at the same time. Or measure the voltage across a lone LED with your current meter.

Comment: Check the impedance of your fluke using another meter.

Comment: A multimeter set on 'voltage' measure will have an impedance of around 10Meg ohm.  i.e.  No way would a properly functioning meter cause this problem.   Your problem is elsewhere.   Also, failing to 'zero' a meter because there's a couple ohms 'bounce' is not really unusual.   It's the contact resistance of your probes.  You might have a tiny bit of dirt on them.  Try again, but squeeze them REALLY HARD, and your reading should settle.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe when you push down on the pin to measure the voltage it causes a flex action that activates a short?  I would make plenty of test voltage measurements with your meter, to eliminate it as the culprit.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions!